# a2dismod php7.0

Tags: 14.04, php, php7

I installed PHP 5.6 and 7.0 via ppa:ondrej/php on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine, but I want to have php 5.6 enabled and 7.0 disabled. I tried doing that by typing

```
sudo a2enmod php5.6
```

and

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0
```

but **php -v** still says im on the latest version:

```
php -v
PHP 7.0.8-3+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-3+deb.sury.org~trusty+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Retinas
```

Is there another way to disable PHP7.0?

Comment: Did you restart apache using `sudo service apache2 restart`?

Comment: Yes I did, but the version that it's showing right there is for CLI. I think the configuration for apache2 is correct, but there are some scripts that require CLI scripts to be executed by cron. So the CLI version must be 5.6 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the following command: `sudo update-alternatives --config php`

Comment: This worked like a charm! I didn't know about this command, thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: Nice, now i have 5.6 instead php7.2 running because i had the same problem here. thank you @garakkio